# Nodejs request Uncaught Error: write EPROTO when against port 443

Tags: node.js, request

I get the error Uncaught Error: write EPROTO when attempting to use my API through the nodejs request module on port 443. It works if I change the port to a non-443 port and requests to the app on port 443 work through the browser and curl.

Why would I get EPROTO and how might I fix it to get my automated tests working again?

Asked for code, it's just an https server with a simple request:

```
var server = https.createServer ({secureProtocol: 'TLSv1_2_method',
        key  : fs.readFileSync('key'),
        cert : fs.readFileSync('cert'),
        ca: [
            fs.readFileSync('othercert')
        ]
    }, app);
```

And a simple request:

```
var request = require('request');
var basepath = "https://localhost";

var req_opts = {
    method: "POST",
    uri: basepath + '/myroute',
    body: {
    },
    rejectUnauthorized: false,
    json: true
}

request(req_opts, function(err, response, body){
    if(err){
        console.log(err);
        throw(err);
    }
    console.log(body);
});
```

This only happens on my local windows machine, not on the remote ubuntu server. Both have node version 4.2.3

Searching it looks like the request might not be able to negotiate a cipher, but then why does it succeed if not on port 443?

Comment: Show us the code that is generating this error please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Skype was also listening locally on port 443 which is why this was occurring.

Comment: Please use the edit link on your question to add additional information. The Post Answer button should be used only for complete answers to the question. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/10530069)

Comment: This is an answer to the question. The request was failing to connect to skype, not the nodejs app.